# How to Concatenate "Jagged" Tensors

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am trying to write an implementation of [this](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P14-1062) paper in TensorFlow and I have come across a bit of a snag. In my pooling layer, I have to concatenate everything together. This is the code I use:

```
    pooled_outputs = []
    for i, filter_size in enumerate(filter_sizes):
        with tf.name_scope("conv-maxpool-%s" % filter_size):
            # Conv layer
            filter_shape = [filter_size, embedding_size, 1, num_filters]
            # W is the filter matrix
            W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1), name="W")
            b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_filters]), name="b")
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
                self.embedded_chars_expanded,
                W,
                strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                padding="VALID",
                name="conv"
            )

            # Apply nonlinearity
            h = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b), name="relu")

            # Max-pooling layer over the outputs
            pooled = tf.nn.max_pool(
                h,
                ksize=[1, sequence_lengths[i] - filter_size + 1, 1, 1],
                strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                padding="VALID",
                name="pool"
            )
            pooled_outputs.append(pooled)

    # Combine all of the pooled features
    num_filters_total = num_filters * len(filter_sizes)

    print(pooled_outputs)
    pooled_outputs = [tf.reshape(out, ["?", 94, 1, self.max_length]) for out in pooled_outputs] # The problem line

    self.h_pool = tf.concat(3, pooled_outputs)
```

When I run this code, it prints out this for `pooled_outputs`:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'conv-maxpool-3/pool:0' shape=(?, 94, 1, 128) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'conv-maxpool-4/pool:0' shape=(?, 51, 1, 128) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'conv-maxpool-5/pool:0' shape=(?, 237, 1, 128) dtype=float32>]
```

I originally tried this code without the `pooled_outputs = [tf.reshape(out, ["?", 94, 1, self.max_length]) for out in pooled_outputs]` line in there and I got this error:

```
ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 51 and 237
```

When I added in the reshape line, I got this error:

```
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got 94
```

The second error I know is because I passed a "?" for the new size, and the first error I think is because the tensors aren't the same size. **How could I properly pad these Tensors so I can concatenate them with no problems?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `-1` as one of the component of the shape to the `tf.reshape` method; it will be automatically inferred from the the shape of you tensor so the total size will be the same.

So, try to change the problem line to

```
pooled_outputs = [tf.reshape(out, [-1, 94, 1, self.max_length]) for out in pooled_outputs]
```

See the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/shapes_and_shaping#reshape) for details